# How to extract required information from a file in Java?

Tags: java

**Here is the contents of the file:**

```
  {"s_raw_message2":"something","CONNECTION_METHOD":"WMS","i_RXBufferLength":"2638","o":"1","DEVICE_OFFSET":"System=0#0;Application=0#0;Security=20150703100915.620080-000#984726;","s_ReporterHost":"ip","CONNECTION_MODE":"WMSapp","s_RV25":"FF98CA90-0394-1033-B130-001D92DD737D","i_TrustDeviceTime":"","s_RV24":"3642BCF0-0394-1033-8342-7C050726582F","s_RV23":"3642BCF0-0394-1033-8310-7C050726582F","s_ReporterPort":"49289","s_RV22":"6D6F80B1-02DF-1033-851D-001D92DD737D","s_Version":"2011.1r4-201409300209-release","s_RV21":"C76D2820-C395-1029-BB86-001321B5C0B3","s_RXBufferString":"something","s_ObserverHost":"ip","s_chainSequence":"34","s_sha256Hash":"dee6e845e41c65d5839198c7dd1052c5de7a53fcd885d3eb1d5491d2322c1a96","s_chainId":"1435917933352","s_ObserverIP":"ip"}
  {"s_raw_message2":"something","CONNECTION_METHOD":"WMS","i_RXBufferLength":"2638","o":"1","DEVICE_OFFSET":"System=0#0;Application=0#0;Security=20150703100915.620080-000#984726;","s_ReporterHost":"ip","CONNECTION_MODE":"WMSapp","s_RV25":"FF98CA90-0394-1033-B130-001D92DD737D","i_TrustDeviceTime":"","s_RV24":"3642BCF0-0394-1033-8342-7C050726582F","s_RV23":"3642BCF0-0394-1033-8310-7C050726582F","s_ReporterPort":"49289","s_RV22":"6D6F80B1-02DF-1033-851D-001D92DD737D","s_Version":"2011.1r4-201409300209-release","s_RV21":"C76D2820-C395-1029-BB86-001321B5C0B3","s_RXBufferString":"something","s_ObserverHost":"ip","s_chainSequence":"34","s_sha256Hash":"dee6e845e41c65d5839198c7dd1052c5de7a53fcd885d3eb1d5491d2322c1a96","s_chainId":"1435917933352","s_ObserverIP":"ip"}
```

There are similar entries in this file which I want to extract information from this file and store it in another file in the form of key value pairs e.g:

```
s_raw_message2 something
CONNECTION_METHOD WMS 
//and so on
```

Please help me to write a Java program for this.

Comment: Looks like JSON to me. Treat it as such.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html should be useful.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, but you can split each line first by comma, then split each smaller piece by semicolon.  This will leave you with array containing one key and one value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks something like this JSON file,

```
{


"u1":{ "uname":"priya","age":22,"country":"India"},

"u2":{ "uname":"usha","age":22,"country":"India"},

"u3":{ "uname":"dharshini","age":22,"country":"India"},

"u4":{ "uname":"mom","age":22,"country":"India"},

"u5":{ "uname":"dad","age":22,"country":"India"},

"u6":{ "uname":"sis","age":22,"country":"India"},

"u7":{ "uname":"bro","age":22,"country":"India"}

}
```

you can parse this JSON file using the ajax request like my code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function ajax_get_json()





{

    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    hr.open("GET", "JSON/mylist.json", true);

    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json",true);

    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {

           /*  var return_data = hr.responseText; */

           var data=JSON.parse(hr.responseText);

           var status=document.getElementById("status");

           status.innerHTML = "";

           /* status.innerHTML=data.u1.country;  */

           for(var obj in data)

               {

               status.innerHTML+=data[obj].uname+" is in "+data[obj].country+"<br/>";
               }

        }
    }
    hr.send(null);

    status.innerHTML = "requesting...";
}
</script>
<body>
<div id="status"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">ajax_get_json();</script>
</body>
</html>
```